# L Shape Appearing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, shapes

There is a weird L shape appearing in certain areas of this site in IE browsers. Any idea what that is?

[image]

Comment: I dont see any L Shapes, where are they appearing?

Comment: Just figured it out. It was a hidden character in the HTML. Probably happened when I copied the text over from Photoshop.

Comment: No Problem, happens to us all at one time or another